# how do i put the command "commands" inside gdbinit?

Tags: c, gdb

How do I put the command "commands break#" inside .gdbinit? I tried this but failed. Thank you

```
define macro1
   b func1
   commands
      p func1_var
   end # gdb complaints that "This command cannot be used at the top level."
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using `commands` **with `s`** instead of `command` (yes, I know your post has the `s`).

That was the cause of the problem for me, but I don't understand why.

GDB 7.11, Ubuntu 16.10.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me.  You probably have an older version of gdb.  Upgrading will fix it.  You could try looking in gdb bugzilla to see when the bug was fixed, if that is important to you.